# Universal Boolean formatting in GridField

Tags: php, silverstripe

With boolean fields the summary shows the value as 0 or 1 by default...

```
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {

    private static  $db = array(
        'Name'      => 'Varchar(255)',
        'MyBoolean' => 'Boolean',
    );

    public static $summary_fields = array (
        'Name',
        'MyBoolean',
    );
}
```

...I know how to change this to Yes or No using casting...

```
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {

    private static  $db = array(
        'Name'      => 'Varchar(255)',
        'MyBoolean' => 'Boolean',
    );

    public static $casting = array (
        'MyBooleanText' => 'Text',
    );

    public function MyBooleanText() {
        return $this->MyBoolean ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    }

    public static $summary_fields = array (
        'Name',
        'MyBooleanText',
    );
}
```

...however my question is how to change every value by default to show this in the summary rows without having to setup casting for each object?

Comment: Note, in SilverStripe 3.1+ all these static variables should be declared as `private`.

Comment: Did you try something like     `private static $casting = array (
        'MyBoolean' => 'Nice',
    );` ??

Comment: I had not tried that @wmk but I have now and it didn't make a change, why did that work for you?  I mean if that could go into an extension for all dataobjects it might work...

Answer (score 1):

In you're `$summary_fields` you just need to tack on the `.Nice` method to your boolean.

E.g:

```
class MyDataObject extends DataObject {

    static  $db = array(
        'Name'      => 'Varchar(255)',
        'MyBoolean' => 'Boolean',
    );

    public static $summary_fields = array (
        'Name' => 'Name',
        'MyBoolean.Nice' => 'MyBoolean',
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm having strange results with this... where the columns disappear... but I'm not able to reproduce yet in a simple way.  However my main issue with this is that it doesn't solve it generically - I've still got to manually update every summary_fields

Comment: This is awesome. I've been writing methods like in the OP like a chump!